# Cython development workflow?

Tags: python, workflow, cython

I'm quite new to [Cython](http://cython.org/), and I come from a web development background. I'm wondering if there's is a workflow for Cython development that's similar to workflows I'm familiar with from web development.

For example, when using CoffeeScript to develop a Node.js web app, I have a Cakefile that watches for changes in the CoffeeScript source and automatically compiles the source to Javascript every time a `.coffee` file is written.

What is the proper way to accomplish something similar in a Cython development environment?

Comment: At least under Flask and I think Django as well, if you are running a dev server, the process monitors all the files the interpreter has opened, and if any change, it restarts the dev server.  Since there's no compilation step (at least one that is separate from the runtime) necessary in Python, it's a bit simpler to manage than what you describe. For a non-local system, usually, you'd set up a post-commit hook on your VCS to package/deploy/restart your app in your development environment.

Comment: @SilasRay, to clarify, I'm actually not developing a web app, and I'm writing Cython in addition to Python. Cython is similar to Python but does have a compilation step. So I'm looking for a (non-web) development workflow that automatically compiles Cython, if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, from my experience this kind of workflow is not particularly customary outside web development. However, there are a couple of options that come at least close to what you ask for.

You may want to use some sort of automated build tool like SCons. The Cython developers even provide a [build tool](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Tools/site_scons/site_tools/cython.py) for it.

Then there is setuptools/distutils, which are mostly for packaging Python software but also support building C extensions. I think, this is even the canonical way of building Cython source into shared objects.

There is another alternative also part of Cython itself: using [pyximport](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/pyximport) you can simply import Cython modules like so:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import foo
```

You don't have to worry about compilation then, since pyximport automatically compiles the module on import if necessary.

I hope one of these options at least resembles what you were looking for ;)

Comment: Thanks! `pyximport` is definitely the closest thing to what I'm looking for, since it obviates the need for such a workflow entirely. Then when I distribute a release, I'll just compile everything once and ship it.